# Add delay to a play list - how to

Tags: javascript, html, video

How do I add a little delay before my playlist? I've tried inserting everywhere and it didn't work.

The script for my playlist (works great):

```
function shuffle (array) {
      var i = 0
        , j = 0
        , temp = null

    for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
  }
}

function play_vid() {
    video.src = links[current]
    video.play();
    if(current!=links.length) {
        current++;
    }
}

var video = $("#w-video").get(0);
var current = 0;
var links = [];
playlist = $('#playlist');
tracks = playlist.find('li a');

$.each(tracks, function(){
    links.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
shuffle(links);
play_vid();


video.onended = function(e) {
    play_vid();
};
```

I've found this script which adds Delay to a simple html5 player but doesn't work with my playlist.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("w-video").play();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: adding the timeout in `play_vid()` should do the trick, no?

Comment: Maybe. But where do I put it? I'm still a beginner at Javascript.